# how the .exe file interact with Windows kernel? same for Linux .bin file

Tags: linux, windows, compiler-construction

Lets say I have a `A.exe` file and I'd like to run it on my windows machine X. 
I'd like to know how this `A.exe` file interacts with the Windows kernel functions in X? Does `A.exe` file already contain all the Windows kernel functions going to be invoked inside its own binary file? or `A.exe` will go to find the address of kernel functions in  machine X and call it?

And similarly, how a .bin file interacts with Linux kernel functions?

Comment: What are you thinking of as a Linux ".bin file"? That doesn't sound familiar to me.

Comment: You should read the wikipedia page about [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).

Comment: @duskwuff: He's probably just referring to ELFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excutable file or libraries will execute an special instruction such as `int 0x80` or `sysenter` and cause an exception. Then the machine looks up a table called IDT (for `int 0x80`) or enter the syscall handler speicified in MSR (for `sysenter`) and start to execute system call handler functions

Answer (score 1):

A .exe file will link in Windows .dll files and call those (by loading the DLL to memory, then using a name->memory mapping in the DLL).   Some of the .dll calls will just stay in userland and do calculations/return a value.  Some will call an interrupt, which will cause an interrupt handler implemented by the OS to run.  This interrupt handler has the right to raise its priority and access to all the OS's memory.  It can either do any further actions directly or schedule them to be done by an OS thread at a later time.  But the code for all of those functions is in the DLL.  The code for the interrupt handler and any routines it may call or cause to be called is in some other file launched when loading the OS.

Comment: In this case, a program that can be run in Linux2.x may not be able to run on Linux3.x, may it?

Comment: That can happen on some OSes.  Linux gets around this because the executable will typically link in the required libraries (like libc) dynamically via a similar method to Windows.  Then so long as you have valid libraries for that OS version you're good.  If you're statically linked, you have to hope that the OS didn't change its interface between versions.